# Chef - if node.name is in template list, tag server

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

We have an issue where we don't have admin privileges to tag servers simply with knife.  How would I tell Chef to read the template and if the template includes the node.name of the server to tag it.

I know I can tag servers with tag('tagnamehere')  But the code surrounding that... I don't know if that will work.  Or if "Template.readlines" is a search function instead of "File.readlines".

```
if Template.readlines('template1.erb').grep(/#{node.name}/).any?
tag('mytag')
end
```

Not sure how to accomplish this feat. But trying very hard to understand as an Ops person.

Comment: So did you try your `File.readlines` or `Template.readlines`? What was the error?

Comment: Have you actually tried this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly reading the static template erb file and you are looking for `#{node.name}` variable used or not.

In this case solution would be skipping string interpolation by using `\` in grep

```
if Template.readlines('template1.erb').grep(/\#{node.name}/).any?
    tag('mytag')
end
```